# view based and navigation based system

Tags: iphone

what is difference between view based and navigation based system in iphone . which one better to use and when?

Answer (score 1):

if you have hierarchy of views, use navigation based else use view controller based.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about default templates that Xcode offers you to start your project with. It's not like they're different "systems" per se, they're just different starting points.

A view template is good if your app is one screen, or maybe a couple screens. Movement between those screens is up to you (and there are some pretty easy and good tools for animation screen changes, but you have to hook into those yourself).

A navigation template is good if you're going to be navigating a hierarchy of data, possibly with lists, sublists, detail screens, etc. Shifting between views is done with a call to UINavigationController, that handles all the transitioning business for you.

Answer (score 1):

navigation based system is used if you want to use something like moving from main view to its inner view

like parent to child then subchild and so on...

While if you have no such hierarchy then you can use view based..

Navigation Based gives you a flexibility to reverse back to the view controller which you have already visited. like say for example you move 1->2->3->4->5 now if you want to go to 2 you can go easily. Navigation adds a top bar while view based is used if you dont want any kind of hierarchy..

hAPPY cODING...